# Get search value in state in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in ReactJS and trying to get the search input box value and store it in a state.

My code:

```
<form className="search-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input type="search" name="search" ref={(input) => this.query = input}
                               placeholder="Search..." />
      <button className="search-button" type="submit" id="submit">Go!</button>
</form>
```

Inside constructor:

```
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
```

And

```
handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({search: this.query.value});
        console.log(this.state.search) //Returns undefined
        e.currentTarget.reset();
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use controlled input approach.

```
state = {
   value: null,
}

handleValue = (e) => this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
```

Then you don't have to use `ref`.

```
<input 
   type="search" 
   name="search" 
   onChange={this.handleValue}
   placeholder="Search..." 
/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible not to have the page refresh. It refreshes the page when I click submit button.

Comment: You need to call `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behavior of submitting the form.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra Or remove `type="submit"` from button :)) I mean, change it into e.g. `type="button"`

Comment: @kinduser Yes I am getting the value now. Many thanks.

Comment: @kinduser One small issue. The console shows the word but one letter less. For eg if I type Sun in the box console shows Su.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra In which console.log my friend?

Comment: @kinduser Sorry it's in Chrome

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra If you console.log value in "handleSubmit" function, it should be correct value. `console.log(this.state.value)`

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you:

```
import React from 'react';
class search extends React.Component{
    constructor(props)
    {
      super(props);
      this.state = {value: ''};
      this.addValue = this.addValue.bind(this);
      this.updateInput = this.updateInput.bind(this);
    }

    addValue(evt)
    {
      evt.preventDefault();
      if(this.state.value !==undefined)
      {
        alert('Your input value is: ' + this.state.value)
      }
    }
    updateInput(evt){
      this.setState({value: evt.target.value});   
        }

    render()
    {
      return (
      <form onSubmit={this.addValue}>
      <input type="text" onChange={this.updateInput} /><br/><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
      )
    }
}
export default search;
```